# How to compare two 2d arrays

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multidimensional-array

i am using visual studio c# win form. . . i have 2d array of textboxes and i have another 2d array of valid solved sudoku i want to compare textbox's text to sudoku array but its not working.Here is my code:

```
        private void Isvalid()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    if (copy[i, j] == textbox[i, j].Text)
                        isvalid = true;


        }
        private void check()
        {
            Isvalid();
            if (isvalid)
                MessageBox.Show("NO");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("YES");

        }
```

Can anyone plz help me. . .
THANx in Advance. . .
Thanx to all who answerd. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not (re)set the `isvalid` variable to false, if the arrays are not equal.

You pass the result of the `Isvalid` method through a shared variable. Your code will be much clearer if you pass the result of the comparison as the method result.

```
private bool Isvalid()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (copy[i, j] != textbox[i, j].Text) {
                return false;  // If one is not equal, the two arrays differ
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can test for:

```
if (Isvalid()) {
   // your code here
}
```

Even better will be if you pass the two arrays as arguments.

Comment: when i press button without doing any thing it shows Message YES

Comment: i am trying to change back color of those text boxes that were unmatched. . .can you plz help me

Answer (score 1):

I would put a breakpoint on the

```
if (copy[i, j] == textbox[i, j].Text)
```

line and visually see if what you see in the Text box is what the array contains.
It might be as simple as needing to do a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

textbox[i, j].Text

here you need to convert the values in the textbox matrix to integer before comparing. That will solve the problem.

Also you need to set invalid as false and after making it true break out of loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Isvalid()
{
    isvalid = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (copy[i, j] != textbox[i, j].Text)
            {
                isvalid = false;
                return;
            }
}
```

In your routine, you'd set isvalid to true whenever one number matches. You'd rather need to set it to false if a number doesn't match.